# Is an AR(1) process with Bernoulli errors mixing or ergodic?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, time-series, stationary-processes, mixing

Before the $\text{AR}(1)$ model, first look at a simpler example

$$y_t=\rho^t y_0+\epsilon_t$$

where $0<\rho<1$ and $\epsilon_t\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \text{Bernoulli} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)$ i.e. $\epsilon_t$ has $50\%$ chance of being $1$ and $50\%$ chance of being $0$. Similarly, $y_0$ also follows the distribution $\text{Bernoulli} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.For finite $t$, $y_t$ has 4 outcomes with 25% chance for each: $0$, $1$, $\rho^t$ and $\rho^t+1$ and

\begin{align}
P(y_t=1,y_0=1) &= P(y_0=1)P(y_t=1|y_0=1) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \times 0 \\
&= 0 \\
&\neq P(y_0=1)P(y_t=1) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{4} \\
&= \frac{1}{8}
\end{align}

Obviously, $y_t$ converges to $\epsilon_t$ almost surely (since $P(\underset{t\to\infty}{\lim}\rho^ty_0=0)=1$), which is independent of $y_0$, and $y_t-\epsilon_t=O_{a.s.}(\rho^t)$. It seems true to me that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}[P(y_t=1,y_0=1)-P(y_0=1)P(y_t=1)]=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=0$$

and

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}[P(y_t=1|y_0=1)-P(y_t=1)]=0$$

Hence the sequence looks mixing (strong and uniform). I am not sure about the size of mixing and the rate of convergence i.e

$$P(y_t=1,y_0=1) - P(y_0=1)P(y_t=1) = \mathcal{O}(?)$$

---

Now, an $\text{AR}(1)$ model with Bernoulli errors takes the form below:

$$y_t=\rho y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$

where $y_0=0$ and $\epsilon_t\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\text{Bernoulli} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. For this model, one can have

$$y_{t+n}=\rho^n y_{t}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\rho^{n-i}\epsilon_{t+i}$$

Similar to the first example, this sequence also looks uniform/strong mixing, though I am not sure how to show it. Could anyone shed some light for me?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is ergodic, but not strong mixing at leasts for $\rho \in (0, 1/2]$.

**Ergodicity**

To see it's ergodic, note that any strongly stationary causal solution of the $AR(1)$ equation $$x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t \sim \mathrm{IID}(0, \sigma^2)$ is ergodic. To see this, we note that
$$x_t = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k \epsilon_{t-k} = f(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-1, \ldots})$$ is the measurable image of an $L^2$ IID (hence ergodic) sequence; since ergodicity is preserved under measurable maps (cf. Billingsley Theorem 36.4), $x_t$ is ergodic.

In your example, to get to your desired form, write your errors as $\gamma_t = \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon_t$ where $\epsilon_t \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\{\pm 1/2\})$, set $\mu = \frac{1}{2(1-\rho)}$, and let $x_t = y_t - \mu$. Then, you get that $x_t$ satisfies the $AR(1)$ dynamics $x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + \gamma_t$, implying it (and thus $y$) is ergodic.

**Mixing**

That $y_t$ is not strongly mixing for $\rho \in (0, 1/2]$ is precisely the content of [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3213710) paper. They conjecture that the restriction on $\rho$ may not be necessary, but I don't know what happens for $\rho > 1/2$.

---

**References**

Billingsley. 1995. Probability and Measure.

Andrews, Donald WK. "Non-strong mixing autoregressive processes." Journal of Applied Probability 21.4 (1984): 930-934.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your answers, Jose. I have looked at the Andrews' paper. It does help me understand the related concepts better.

But I still have some questions related to strong mixing, weak mixing and ergodicity. In Andrews' paper, he defined $A=\{X_t|X_t\in (0,\rho)\}$ and $B_s=\{X_{t+s}|X_{t+s}\in \overset{2^s}{\underset{j=1}{\cup}}(w_j,w_j+\rho^{s+1})\}$, where $w_j$s are the possible values of $\sum_{l=0}^{s-1}\rho^l\epsilon_{t+s-l}$: $0,\rho^{s-1},\rho^{s-2},\dots,\rho,\dots,1,\dots,1+\rho+\dots+\rho^{s-1}$ ($2^s$ outcomes in total, the same probability for each outcome). It is clear that $\mu(B_s)=(2\rho)^s\rho$, where $\mu(\cdot)$ is the Lebesgue measure. If $\rho>\frac{1}{2}$, $\mu(B_s)$ will increase with $s$. But if $\rho$ gets too large, $P(A)$ will get small. If $0<\rho\leq\frac{1}{2}$, one can have $\mu(B_s)\leq\rho$ for any $s\geq 1$. Note that $X_{t+s} \in [0,\frac{1}{1-\rho})$ with $\frac{1}{1-\rho}>\rho$. Therefore, $P(B_s)<1$ and $P(A)(P(B_s|A)-P(B_s))=P(A)(1-P(B_s))>0$ for any s, which means an AR(1) model with Bernoulli errors is not strong mixing when $\rho\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$. It is neither weak mixing since $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{s=1}^{n}|P(A)||P(B_s|A)-P(B_s)|\neq 0$. For example, suppose $t$ is sufficiently large. When $\rho=\frac{1}{2}$, $X_t\sim U[0,2)$ (the possible outcomes are $0,\frac{1}{2^{t-1}},\frac{2}{2^{t-1}},\dots,\frac{2^t-1}{2^{t-1}}=2-(\frac{1}{2})^{t-1})$. For any $s$, $X_{t+s}$ is also uniformly distributed between 0 and 2 and hence $P(B_s)=\frac{1}{4}$ with  $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{s=1}^{n}|P(A)||P(B_s|A)-P(B_s)|=\frac{3}{16}$. To my confusion, on P.931 of Andrews' paper, he said "All $L^2$ AR(1) processes are ordinary mixing see Hannan (1970), Chapter IV, Theorem 3". I looked at Hannan's theorem. It seems to me that Hannan's definition of mixing, (2.1) on P.202, is strong mixing.

Jose, I am not sure what you mean by ergodic. Do you mean $\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T X_t}{T}$ converges in probability to $E(X_t)$? When I looked at [this paper](https://users.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/wlln.pdf) (P.2), ergodicity means $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{s=1}^{n}P(A)(P(B_s|A)-P(B_s))=0$. Obviously, for $\rho=\frac{1}{2}$, the AR(1) model is not ergodic either based on this definition.

For the first example: $y_t=\rho^t y_0+\epsilon_t$. One can construct $A=\{y_0|y_0=1\}$ and $B_t=\{y_t|y_t\in\{\rho^t,1+\rho^t\}\}$ to have $P(B_t|A)=1$. It does not appear to be strong mixing since $P(A)(P(B_t|A)-P(B_t))=\frac{1}{4}$ for any t. It is not possible to find $T(v)$ given any small $v>0$ such that $|P(A)(P(B_t|A)-P(B_t))|<v$ when $t>T(v)$. Hence the sequence in the first example is neither strong/weak mixing, nor ergodic. Please correct me if I am wrong. It seems different people talk about the same terms differently in this literature.

**References**

HANNAN, E. J. (1970) Multiple Time Series. Wiley, New York

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2040030)

Comment: I answered my own questions, though during the process I had come up with more questions, which are related to my original questions.

Comment: You need to edit your post or make another one then. only the answers to the question go in the answers section, you cannot add additional questions, even if they are related.